# Как привязать клавиатуру Бота ВК к айди пользователя который её открывает

Tags: python, python-3.x, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Я добавил клавиатуру Бота ВК в беседу, но при открытии и закрытии она отрывается и закрывается всем участникам беседы. Как можно привязать клавиатуру к каждому пользователю по отдельности?
Вот код клавиатуры бота:

```py
    def create_keyboard():
    keyboard = vk_api.keyboard.VkKeyboard(one_time=False)

    keyboard.add_button("Команды", color=vk_api.keyboard.VkKeyboardColor.DEFAULT)
    keyboard.add_button("Закрыть", color=vk_api.keyboard.VkKeyboardColor.POSITIVE)

    keyboard.add_line()
    keyboard.add_button("Реклама", color=vk_api.keyboard.VkKeyboardColor.NEGATIVE)

    keyboard.add_line()
    keyboard.add_button("Админы", color=vk_api.keyboard.VkKeyboardColor.PRIMARY)
    keyboard.add_button("Аниме", color=vk_api.keyboard.VkKeyboardColor.PRIMARY)

    return keyboard.get_keyboard() 

def create_empty_keyboard():
    keyboard = vk_api.keyboard.VkKeyboard.get_empty_keyboard()

    return keyboard

    keyboard = create_keyboard()
            empty_keyboard = create_empty_keyboard()

     if response == "йокки привет":
                api.messages.send(chat_id= event.chat_id, message="Приветики", keyboard=keyboard, random_id=0)
     if response[27:34] == "закрыть":
                api.messages.send(peer_id=event.obj.peer_id or event.message.peer_id, message="Закрываем", keyboard=empty_keyboard, random_id=0)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В беседе привязать клавиатуру к конкретному пользователю **невозможно**

Comment: А как насчёт базы данных?

Comment: Это тоже ничего не даст, ВК просто не предоставляет такой возможности. Максимум что можно сделать, это отправлять клавиатуру пользователю в личку (но это не удобно и стоит учесть, что пользователь мог ни разу не писать боту в личку и вылетит ошибка)